# Are NHS Covid tests okay for travelling to the US after Nov 8?

Tags: usa, air-travel, international-travel

The NHS gives out free covid tests. Can I take one the day before travelling, put the test in a plastic bag and use that as evidence?

Or could I book an NHS PCR test and use the text/email receipt as evidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. COVID-19 testing for the purposes of international travel is not available on the NHS. https://www.fitfortravel.nhs.uk/advice/disease-prevention-advice/covid-19-health-considerations-for-travel/coronavirus-covid-19-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: The NHS has no control over what tests the US authorities accept. The US might still decide to accept an NHS test even if the NHS doesn’t want you to use it for that purpose.